# Need to Convert Set of Coordinates

Tags: php, coordinate-systems

I'm stuck with another coordinates related query here. I have a number of CSV files and they all have a bunch of coordinates mentioned however the coordinates are in differing formats like some files have the coordinates shown as so:

```
40.0873°N 20.1531°E
```

While some have them as so:

```
27°50′21″N 00°11′07″W
```

I need a way to set up a function in PHP that:

First of all deduces what format the coordinates are in

Then convert the coordinates into latitude and longitudes as so:

```
37.235
-115.811111
```

Plus I understand the second format is Hours Minutes Seconds - the thing is that how do I extract the hours minutes and seconds from this kind of string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code:

```
print_r(parse("40.0873°N 20.1531°E"));
print_r(parse("27°50′21″N 00°11′07″W"));
function parse($coord)
{
    $strings = split(' ',$coord);
    $ret['lat'] = degree2decimal($strings[0]);
    $ret['lon'] = degree2decimal($strings[1]);
    return $ret;
}
function degree2decimal($deg_coord="")
{
    $dpos=strpos($deg_coord,'°');
    $mpos=strpos($deg_coord,'‘');
    $spos=strpos($deg_coord,'"');
    $mlen=(($mpos-$dpos)-1);
    $slen=(($spos-$mpos)-1);
    $direction=substr(strrev($deg_coord),0,1);
    $degrees=substr($deg_coord,0,$dpos);
    $minutes=substr($deg_coord,$dpos+1,$mlen);
    $seconds=substr($deg_coord,$mpos+1,$slen);
    $seconds=($seconds/60);
    $minutes=($minutes+$seconds);
    $minutes=($minutes/60);
    $decimal=($degrees+$minutes);
    if (($direction=="S") or ($direction=="W"))
        { $decimal=$decimal*(-1);}
    return $decimal;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [lat] => 40.08732425
    [lon] => 20.153142527778
)
Array
(
    [lat] => 27.835277777778
    [lon] => -0.18333333333333
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those are the only two formats, you could find which format a string was by searching in it for ' or " (you could use [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for this).

If the format is the first type there is almost no conversion needed - use N/S and E/W to determine if you need to make the value negative or not.

If you have degrees, minutes and seconds then you can get the values from the string using [sscanf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php).  Once you have the individual values then you can find the decimal degrees as degrees + minutes / 60 + seconds / (60 * 60).

Answer (score 1):

What you need are some regular expressions. You can use a regular expression in combination with the functions in php to extract whatever you want from a given string. What I would probably do is use a regex to check the format of a given file and then I would iterate through each line of a file, using a regex to extract the relevant information. For example, you could use a regular expression like `[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,4}°(N|W|E|S)` to check whether something matches the first type. Then you could match each line of the input against something like `([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,4})°(N|W|E|S)` with `preg_match_all` and extract the relevant data from the `matches` array. From here, you will have all the data needed for the conversion. A similar thing could be done for the other type. Note that I don't have a php install to test these Regular Expressions against, so they may need some slight tweaking to avoid php blowing up when it reads them (most likely the `°` character may need to be encoded differently, although you could likely just use the `.` meta-character, as it will match any single non-space character).

Some good resources for regular expressions:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/index.html
- [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

As mentioned in the SO link above, having some sort of tester is quite useful for generating regular expressions, whether that be something like [RegEx Buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/), [Reggy](http://reggyapp.com/), or [Kodos](http://kodos.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: It could make for an elegant solution.